# Three term inner and outer solution to a boundary layer problem

Tags: asymptotics, boundary-value-problem

I am unsure how to proceed with the current equation to determine a three-term outer expansion and three-term inner expansion due to the nature of the equation.

Equation:

$\epsilon \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x$, $y(0) = 0$, $y(1) = 2$

Whilst I only have lecture notes with equations in the form:

$\epsilon \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+ a(x)\frac{dy}{dx} + b(x)y = 0$

I have made an attempt to a solution:

Seeking a solution in the form of

$y(x) = y_0(x) + \epsilon y_1(x) + \epsilon^2 y_2(x) + O(\epsilon^3)$

$=> \epsilon (y_0^{''} + \epsilon y_1^{''} + \epsilon^2 y_2^{''} + O(\epsilon^3)) + y_0^{'} + \epsilon y_1^{'} + \epsilon^2 y_2^{'} + O(\epsilon^3) = 2x$

Equating powers of $\epsilon$

$\epsilon^0: y_0 = 2x^2$

$\epsilon^1: y_1 = 6x^2 - 4x$

$\epsilon^2: y_2 = 14x^2 - 12x$

$y_{outer}(x) = 2x^2 + \epsilon (6x^2 - 4x) + \epsilon^2 (14x^2 - 12x)$

applying the transform $y(x) = Y(X)$ and $x = \epsilon X$ we get:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+\frac{dy}{dx} = 2x\epsilon$

again seeking a solution in the form of

$Y_{inner}(X) = Y_0 + \epsilon Y_1 + \epsilon^2 Y_2$

however I am stuck here when attempting to use the following formula:

$\frac{d^2Y_n}{dX} + \frac{dY_n}{dX} = 2x - \frac{dY_{n-1}}{dX} - Y_{n-1}$

Thanks in advance